# Check id from two tables, if there is no match delete it

Tags: c#

i need to check on TimeEntries from two different databases.

one is where we log our hours(**LogDB**), the other is for managing those hours(**ManagerDB**).

so if the timeEntry is removed from where we log our hours, it needs to be removed from our manager as well.

but how do i check this ?

here i get my data : 
**ManagerDB:**

```
    // get TimeEntries from ManagerDB, add timespan of 10 years.
var DBTimeEntries = GetTimeEntriesFromDB(new TimeSpan(3650, 0, 0, 0));
```

(*returns a list of ID's*)
**LogDB**

```
    // get TimeEntries from LogDB, add timespan of 10 years.
var TickTimeEntries = GetTickTimeEntries<TimeEntry>(new TimeSpan(3650, 0, 0, 0)).Select(x=> x.id);
```

(*returns a list of ID's*)

and here im trying to check if there is no match.

```
foreach (InternExternalId te in DBTimeEntries)
{// Manager Data:
    foreach (int t in TickTimeEntries)
    {// Logger data.

            if (te.TickId != t)
            {
                delete method here...
            }


    }
}
```

it should only delete the data fra ManagerDB, if there is no match what so ever, meaning it has been deleted from LogDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope I got your scenario right. You could use linq instead of the nested foreach statments:

```
var idsToRemove = TickTimerEntries.Except(DBTimeEntries.Select(t => t.TickId)); 
// Entries that existed in LogDB but not in ManagerDB no populate idsToRemove.
// You should now delete the entries which appear in idsToRemove
```

Comment: yep you got the scenario right, looks really clean btw!

Comment: worked perfectly ^^ did not now of except. Thx for the help :D